# How to delay incorrect password timeout to 2nd or 3rd attempt (Windows 8)?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, windows-registry, timeout

I currently have a Windows 8 laptop. Normally, when I type in my password to log in, it does so immediately. However, when I type in an incorrect password, it takes several seconds for it to tell me that I have an incorrect password.

I'm pretty sure that this delay is meant to prevent people from brute forcing my password (or perhaps it's delaying so it can check the Microsoft servers to see if I changed my password), but it is a bit annoying when I only accidentally misspelled my password.

Is there a way to configure my computer so it does the timeout after perhaps the second or third incorrect password attempt?

Alternatively, is there a way to shorten the delay period?

**Edit:**
Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. I'm not actually being locked out to my account. Windows just prevents from re-entering the password for a couple of seconds. Once the timeout period is over (which lasts like 4-5 seconds), it lets me retry.

Comment: Never seen anything about this in group policy and so there's probably no way to configure it via registry either.

Comment: Same problem! any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't lock you out on one failed login attempt, it must be something else.

As far as your question is concerned, the quickest way to change account lockout threshold is from the command-line. Open an elevated command prompt and type in this command:

```
net accounts /lockoutthreshold:3
```

This allows all users on the system up to three login attempts before he/she is locked out of their account. Change the value to anything you wish. Set value to `0` to reset this setting.